# C# XML serialization - Change array item name

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I need to serialize objects with List property to XML to get XML code like this (I know it's not valid XML but my 3rd party application need this format):

```
<Filters>
    <Criteria_0 Parameter="STATUS"
        Operator="EQUAL"
        Value="STARTED" />
    <Criteria_1 Parameter="STATUS" 
        Operator="EQUAL"
        Value="COMPLETED" />
</Filters>
```

I wrote code like this:

```
public class JobStatusListTask
{
    public JobListSettings ListSettings;

    public List<JobFilterCriteria> Filters;

    public JobStatusListTask()
    {
        Filters = new List<JobFilterCriteria>();
        Filters.Add(new JobFilterCriteria("STATUS", CriteriaOperator.Equal, "ERROR"));
    }


    public JobStatusListTask(JobListSettings settings) : this()
    {
        ListSettings = settings;
    }
}

public class JobFilterCriteria : IXmlSerializable
{
    public static int Count = 0;

    public string Parameter;

    public CriteriaOperator Operator;

    public string Value;

    private JobFilterCriteria()
    {
        Parameter = string.Empty;
        Value = string.Empty;
    }

    public JobFilterCriteria(string parameter, CriteriaOperator criteriaOperator, string value)
    {
        Parameter = parameter;
        Operator = criteriaOperator;
        Value = value;
    }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(string.Format("Criteria_{0}", Count++));
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Parameter", Parameter);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Operator", Operator.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", Value);
    }
}
```

It works almost perfect. Serializer return XML code with unnecessary JobFilterCriteria element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Filters>
    <JobFilterCriteria>
        <Criteria_0 
            Parameter="STATUS" Operator="Equal" Value="ERROR" />
    </JobFilterCriteria>
    <JobFilterCriteria>
        <Criteria_1 
            Parameter="STATUS" Operator="Equal" Value="STARTED" />
    </JobFilterCriteria>
</Filters>
```

What I need to change to remove JobFilterCriteria from XML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this code block will solve your problem, you need to serialize JobStatusListTask class.

```
public class JobStatusListTask : IXmlSerializable
{
    public JobListSettings ListSettings;

    public List<JobFilterCriteria> Filters;

    public JobStatusListTask()
    {
        Filters = new List<JobFilterCriteria>();
        Filters.Add(new JobFilterCriteria("STATUS", CriteriaOperator.Equal, "ERROR"));
    }


    public JobStatusListTask(JobListSettings settings) : this()
    {
        ListSettings = settings;
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Filters");
        foreach(var item in Filters)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Criteria", string.Format("Criteria_{0}", Count++));
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Parameter", Parameter);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Operator", Operator.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", Value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on answers, but I don't see how the above compiles as is, and it seems the namespace is being set accidentally, I'm sure you worked it out, but for posterity, a few changes that I believe are needed to make it work as intended:

```
public class JobStatusListTask : IXmlSerializable
{
    public JobListSettings ListSettings;

    public List<JobFilterCriteria> Filters;

    public JobStatusListTask()
    {
        Filters = new List<JobFilterCriteria>();
        Filters.Add(new JobFilterCriteria("STATUS", CriteriaOperator.Equal, "ERROR"));
    }


    public JobStatusListTask(JobListSettings settings) : this()
    {
        ListSettings = settings;
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Filters");
        for(int i = 0; i < Filters.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(string.Format("Criteria_{0}", i));
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Parameter", Parameter);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Operator", Operator.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", Value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

}
```